# Find the index of the first array element divisible by a number

Tags: python, numpy, modulo

I want to find the index of the first array element divisible by a number. I then want to use that result to create a mask array. For example, consider the following array:

```py
arr = np.array([19,49,79,109,139,169,199,229])
```

Say I want a number divisible by 7, I would want to get index 1 and use that to create the array:

```py
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Currently, I have

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([19,49,79,109,139,169,199,229])
x = 7
index = np.array([np.where(arr % x == 0)]).min()
arr_new =  np.zeros(arr.size, dtype=int)
arr_new[index] = 1
print(arr_new)
```

This works, but I have to do this operation on a large scale with many values of x. Is there a better (faster?) way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I'd change about getting the index is how you're extracting the result from `np.where`. It has the list of indices already sorted, so you can just do

```py
index = np.where(arr % x == 0)[0][0]
```

For `arr_new`, you might want that to be a boolean array instead of integers, so you can set `dtype=bool`. One improvement is to use `np.zeros_like`, so you don't need to tell it the size of `arr`.

```py
arr_new = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=bool)
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.full_like`, which might relay your intent more clearly.

```py
arr_new = np.full_like(arr, False)
```